# Reload view data after changes in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a component that displays a table of objects with a button in each row that calls a function to modify an attribute of the selected object. Even though the button works and does modify the attribute I have to manually reload the view to see the changes in the table.

The functions looks like this:

```
accept(id: string) {
    this.service.accept(id).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('done');
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error'):
        });
}
```

And the accept method on my service looks like this:

```
accept(id : string){
    return this.http.put('/myUrl/' +id).map(res => res.json());     
}
```

I want the view to "reload" the moment I push the button displaying the new value correctly without having to reload the page manually. Is that possible and/or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT 1

Here is some more code of the html table with the button i was mentioning:

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{item.date| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="item.status== 0">Pending</td>
            <td *ngIf="item.status== 1">Accepted</td>
            <td *ngIf="item.status== 0">
                <button (click)='accept(item.id)'>Accept</button>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT 2

I just realized that on my original code,in this part of the code :

```
aceptar(id: string) {
    this.propuestaService.aceptarPropuesta(id).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.msg = 'Propuesta Aceptada';
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error'):  <----- Didn't have this here
        });
}
```

I didnt have the console.log('error') line, I had something else there, I added it here just to simplify the question. And I see now that the console is saying that that error is happening, so maybe there is something wrong in that part that is preventing the changes on the view. Still the value is changed when I reload manually.

The error says :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (http.umd.js:753)
at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (MyService.ts:41)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:79)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1083)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6078)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:154)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:335)
```

Comment: Well, you have to call the service to re-retrieve the values from the db, after making changes, to be able to see the new value(s)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the values from the db after making changes. Values do not magically appear without telling the app to do so ;) That's why you are seeing the changes after making a hard refresh, when values are fetched from the db on initialization.

So after you have modified and saved the change you need to call the api again to retrieve the values, so something like this:

```
accept(id: string) {
    this.service.accept(id).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('done');
            this.getData(); // add your equivalent for fetching data here!
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error'):
        });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, still nothing happends when pushing the button and have to reload manually to see the changes.

Comment: The button in the html table that calls the function modifyAttribute() on click.

Comment: Please share some more code... there's very little to work on here. You could also looking into changedetector https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor

Comment: I edited my question with some more code, I dont know if that's the part you needed to see, Tell me if u need something else. The button basically sets the status value to 1 if it was 0, and what I want is the table to display the new status as i click it.

Comment: Well, I can't see anywhere the change of status in your code at all, where is this change happening?

Comment: The angular service( The second block of code that i posted) makes the put request to my backend server where there is method that sets the item value to 1.

Comment: Okay, now it starts to make sense ;) Did you try the changedetector? I don't see why it wouldn't update the values if you are refetching the data after change though...

Comment: Yeah I tried it still nothiing happends I just click the button as it looks as if nothing happened, I reload manually and then I can see the changes.

Comment: Well, strange. I don't know what else to suggest, everything seems in order based on what I am seeing. If you would recreate the issue in a plunker, I'd be happy to take a look at it :)

Comment: As u can tell im really new to angular so I wouldn't know how to set a plunkr :p but thanks for your time and suggestions anyways, I'll keep looking around to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, I have a bit of time here and feeling nice today :D so I can see if I can set up a plunker and test your code, but I see nothing strange here. But you can then at least double check your code :) Hold on a bit and lets see if I can whip up something :)

Comment: I edited the question again becouse i noticed something maybe that tells you something. I'm going to check the plunkr now.

Comment: Well that explains it, the response you are getting from your put request is breaking the app. You need to check what's causing the issue, and what error message is coming from the api. Check your network tab in browser, that should help :)

Comment: Srry forgot to post the error. I edited again, will check the network tab now.

Comment: Error message says to me that there is not valid JSON coming in. This is a backend problem...

Comment: Yeah the PUT request on my API wasn't returning any object back, just making the changes. I never thought it needed to do it. It turns out that making it return the item changed fixes this.:p. Thanks for your time again @AJT_82 you always help in my questions. I will accept your answer because i think that part was needed too.

Comment: You are welcome,glad to help! :) Yes the part (my answer) to re-retrieve the items is necessary after the change, because otherwise the items will not be updated :)